# $null check in velocity

Tags: java, struts, velocity

I came to know about null check using $null in velocity 1.6 through a resource updated by you.
Resource: [Reading model objects mapped in Velocity Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495/reading-model-objects-mapped-in-velocity-templates)
But I am facing so many challenges that there is no $null for null check in velocity as there is no documentation provided about this.
Please provide me with documentation stating $null as valid for null check in velocity.

Answer (score 115):

To check if a variable is not null simply use #if ($variable)

```
#if ($variable) 
 ... do stuff here if the variable is not null
#end
```

If you need to do stuff if the variable is null simply negate the test

```
#if (!$variable)
 ... do stuff here if the variable is null
#end
```

Comment: this would also return true in case of boolean values. This is a nice documentation for null checks : http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull

Comment: following up on @TJ comment, any idea how to import `NullTool` as of recent? It does not appear to be in velocity-tools 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Approach 1: Use the fact that null is evaluated as a false conditional. (cf. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#Conditionals)

```
#if( ! $car.fuel )
```

> Note: The conditional will also pass if the result of $car.fuel is the
> boolean false. What this approach is actually checking is whether the
> reference is null or false.

Approach 2: Use the fact that null is evaluated as an empty string in quiet references. (cf. http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation)

```
#if( "$!car.fuel" == "" )
```

> Note: The conditional will also pass if the result of $car.fuel is an
> empty String. What this approach is actually checking is whether the
> reference is null or empty. BTW, just checking for empty can be
> achieved by:

```
#if( "$car.fuel" == "" )
```

Approach 3: Combine Approach 1 and 2. This will check for null and null only.

```
#if ((! $car.fuel) && ("$!car.fuel" == ""))
```

> Note: The logic underlying here is that: "(null or false) and (null or
>
> > empty-string)" => if true, must be null. This is true because "false and empty-string and not null" is never true. IMHO, this makes the
> > template too complicated to read.

Comment: If you're using velocity for AWS API Gateway, you need `#if($car.fuel == "")` to check for `null` in the response. The implicit approach (`#if($car.fuel)`) will not work.

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but it looks like a direct copy paste from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/VELOCITY/CheckingForNull