# Velocity nulls and empty strings

Tags: java, templates, velocity

In velocity I have a variable which its value is *null*. I don't want to display anything in that case.

Currently the template engine translates "" to *null* so I have to do.

```
#set ( $a = "")
#if ($a) 
   assert("never prints a neither gets here: " + $a)
#end
```

Is there a way I could do that directly? I'd like to be able to make something like:

```
This is the variable $a. ## in case that $a is null i don't want 'dollar a' to be displayed
```

Comment: You might find the following Velocity wiki page interesting: [Checking for null](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull). Also check out [$null check in velocity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3478638/851811)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`$!a` does the trick. You can use this form directly without an `if` check.

Answer (score 27):

### You want Quiet Reference Notation: `$!a`

Here's your example:

```
This is the variable $!a.
```

If `$a` is `null` or `""`, Velocity will render:

```
This is the variable .
```

Official Guide section:
https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to modify your `if` statement per *[Checking for Null](https://wiki.apache.org/velocity/CheckingForNull)* (thanks for the link @xavi-lópez):

> Approach 2: Use the fact that null is evaluated as an empty string in
>   quiet references. (cf.
>   http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#quietreferencenotation)

So, your code would be:

```
#set ( $a = "")
#if ("$a" != "") 
   assert("never prints a neither gets here: " + $a)
#end
```