# Is there a compact way to set a default value when using a Velocity variable (like the Freemarker way)?

Tags: velocity, freemarker

In Freemarker you can

```
<p>${my_var!}</p>
```

to avoid having an error message if my_var is not defined, and

```
<p>${my_var!"this is undefined!"}</p>
```

to set a defaut value for my_var if it is not defined.

What with Velocity? Do you also have a compact syntaxe or do you have to do a if/else statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here :
[Velocity nulls and empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263548/velocity-nulls-and-empty-strings)

solution with velocity :

```
<p>$!my_var</p>
```