# null values showing velocity script instead of empty

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine, xdocreport

I have Invoice object which contains some fields like invoice number, date, customer etc.., I like to print my invoice data for that I used **opensagres.xdocreport** api. In this process I used Velocity Template Engine. If invoice object has no data for some fields then, I got output like below explained.

**I used my template like this.**

```
<h1>Invoice No : $Invoice.number<h1>

<h1>Date : $Invoice.date<h1>
```

**Expected output**

```
Invoice No : INV003

Date : 11-08-2015
```

**but I got like this**

```
Invoice No : INV003

Date : $Invoice.date
```

But I want space if no data for date. plz let me know the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the same than [Velocity nulls and empty strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263548/velocity-nulls-and-empty-strings). In other words try to write :

```
Date : $!Invoice.date
```

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 0):

Invoice.date must be an Object not a Date and you can check the date before generate. If it's not null, then Invoice.date = date, but if null then Invoice.date = "" (String).

Let me know if I helped you.

Comment: I can't change type, it should be Date Type. but it's a null, and I can't handle if it is null.