# How to get the HttpServletRequest within a velocity tool?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlets, velocity

I want to implement a velocity tool that provides a method in order to find out weather a user is logged in or not. I'm using the VelocityLayoutServlet in order to render the templates on each request.

My velocity-tools.xml looks like this:

```
<tools>
    <toolbox scope="request">
       <tool key="user" class="UserTool"/>
    </toolbox>
</tools>
```

My tool class:

```
public class UserTool{

    // How do I get this object?
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return !request.getUserPrincipal().getName().isEmpty();
    }

}
```

How do I get the `HttpServletRequest` object within my tool?

FYI: I'm using container managed authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two flaws:

1. If the request is anonymous, you will receive a NullPointerException
2. Your tool is superfluous because the Velocity-bundled `Servlet` is supposed to add request already into the context: `$request.remoteUser`.

The scope `request` does not denote the HTTP request. It simply reams that this tools is recreated on every rendering request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I'm one step further. Now I can access the user from within the template file. But I need to render some parts of the template only, when the user is logged in. How can I do this? `$request.remoteUser.isEmpty()` works only when the user is logged in.

Comment: @eztam Don't use `isEmpty` you may run into a NPE. Idealy, you work with roles: `$request.isUserInRole`. If you care for authentication only use this idiom `#if ($request.remoteUser) ... #end`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478701/696632).